# Dialogflow создать регистрацию

Tags: dialogflow

Пытался найти информацию, как сделать, чтобы можно было-  удалять или добавлять пользователей. Если человек зарегистрирован, он имеет доступ к информации, а если не зарегистрирован, тогда ему нужно будет зарегистрироваться и самое главное, регистрация считается успешной, если только менеджер подтвердил

То есть блокировать все запросы и просить зарегистрироваться.

Единственное решение, которое ко мне пришло, это интегрировать dialogflow на сайт, который будет работать с telgram или skype. Он же будет проводить регистрацию, если у человека есть доступ, тогда у него будет доступ к dialogflow

Comment: А почему именно diagflow?